# How to properly use screen size in WPF application

Tags: wpf, user-interface

I've done desktop application's GUI for minimum 800x600 pixels. But now I need to make it look good when maximised in any screen size. There is so little to show, I don't know how to adjust the elements in big screen.

**Now in 800x600:**

[image: Now (800x600)]

**Maximised in 1366x768:**

[image: Maximised in 1366x768]

I tried to make them bigger with screen size, but that give them kinda ugly, unsophisticated look. What should I do?

Comment: Are you using using AvalonDock control? Provide the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WPF Grid Layout to position your control. It will stretch the size of your control based on the defined layout.

You can read a tutorial here https://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use Uniform grid in that case

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/uniformgrid-in-wpf/